# Friendly URL inside subfolder with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite my urls to make them seem to have a clean folder strcuture.

I always do this, but usually on the server root with one single .htaccess file.

Recently, I learnt that you can create the .htaccess file in whatever folder you like, and it will have ascending priority.

So, now, I want to rewrite the URL inside a root subfolder, as follows:

**Input**: example.tld/subfolder/whatever
**Behind the scenes**: example.tld/subfolder/index.php?get=whatever

I am trying to achieve it with this .htaccess lines, located in the "subfolder" folder.

```
# Activate
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /subfolder/

# Rewrite
RewriteRule ^/(\w+)/?$ index.php?get=$1
```

Accessing the expected url turns into a 404 error.

mod_rewrite is enabled.

Comment: You certainly can use multiple such dynamic configuration files. But consider that this really slows the server down, since it has to open, read, load, interpret each of those files for every single request. If you instead place those rules inside the http server's host configuration then this is done only once at startup time...

Comment: About your specific rule: take care here, if you use a rewriting rule, then the pattern is applied against the _relative_ path, so _without_ holding a trailing slash. That is why your pattern will _never_ match, there will _never_ be a leading slash in the request in this situation. That is different when rules are defined in the http servers host configuration, there the pattern is applied against clean _absolute_ paths...

Comment: @arkascha Thanks for your time. By "place those rules inside the http server's host configuration", do you mean "by placing those rules in the server root"? or is it something else?

Comment: No, that is something completely different. The apache http server has a configuration section that defines all its setup, what modules are loaded, what hosts are defined, what log files are written where and and and... It is completely separate from the content holding folders in the file system for obvious reasons (security!) and typically located under `/etc/apache2` or `/etc/httpd`. In there different (virtual) hosts can be defined that this http server will serve. That is where such rules belong. You want to start reading the documentation of the apache http server, it seems...

Comment: @arkascha Thank you a lot. Very useful and helpful information.